# Getting an input element through xpath in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, xpath, webview, domdocument

So I am playing with an objective c desktop app(not iOS). I am loading the content of a webpage into a WebView and I want to fill in input fields like username with hardcoded text from the code.

After

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

is called, how can I get to an element based on the XPath?

e.g. for XPaths I want to get to

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div/input
//*[@id="username"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, using JavaScript to manipulate the HTML is more robust and flexible than using XPath, for many reasons. I would suggest you execute the appropriate JavaScript in the web view. Here is an example implementation:

```
- (BOOL) insertFormFieldValues: (UIWebView *) webView
{
    NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"insert your javascript here"];
    return result == RESULT_OK;
}
```

Comment: thanks Angela. Yes I am aware of stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, and even though in this case I have a WebView not an UIWebView that would still work. What I don't know though is how to get that element with that path. I always know the path, it is the same in the form, I just don't know how to get to it.

Comment: In JavaScript the code would be: document.getElementById('username').value = 'myusername';

Comment: thanks Angela. Works. 
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
[sender stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById(\"username\").value = \"xyz\""];